# query-string in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, query-string, react-class-based-component

I show two query strings in my URL like this `**localhost3000/?filter=all&search=something**`
but the problem is when there isn't anything for search my URL still shows `**localhost3000/?filter=all&search=**`
while I want to show search if it uses and when there is no search it shows `**localhost3000/?filter=all**`
this is my code:

```
  replaceUrl = () => {
    const x = {
      filter: this.state.filter,
      search: this.state.searchterm,
    };
    const y = queryString.stringify(x);
    this.props.navigate(`?${y}`);
  };
```

**`replaceUrl`** calls when filter changes or something search

Comment: What's the value of `searchterm` when it's not set? Maybe it is the empty string instead of `undefined`? Try setting it to `undefined` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `search` field if the `this.state.searchterm` exist

```
replaceUrl = () => {
    const x = {
      filter: this.state.filter,
    };

    if (this.state.searchterm) x.search = this.state.searchterm;

    const y = queryString.stringify(x);

    this.props.navigate(`?${y}`);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a class component I'll assume you had no issue wrapping it in a function component to inject the `navigate` function into props. `react-router-dom` v6 has a [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook specifically for working with the URL queryString.

> **Note:**
>
> The `setSearchParams` function works like [navigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate), but only for
> the [search portion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) of the URL.

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

Pass `searchParams` and `setSearchParams` along to your class component and access via props.

```
replaceUrl = () => {
  const { filter, searchterm } = this.state;
  const { searchParams, setSearchParams } = this.props;

  if (filter) {
    searchParams.set("filter", filter);
  }
  if (searchterm) {
    searchParams.set("search", searchterm);
  }

  setSearchParams(searchParams);
};
```